# Does C# Parallel.ForEach introduce a race condition when used to replace file text?

Tags: c#, replace, race-condition, parallel.foreach

Does the following code block in C# introduce a race condition:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(guidDictionary, (dictionaryItem) =>
    {
        var fileName = dictionaryItem.Key;
        var fileText = File.ReadAllText(fileName, Encoding.ASCII);
        Parallel.ForEach(guidDictionary, (guidObj) =>
        {
            fileText = fileText.Replace(guidObj.Value.OldGuid, guidObj.Value.NewGuid);
        });

        File.WriteAllText(fileName, fileText);
    });
```

?

Comment: Should be ok, if those are actual GUIDs you are replacing.

Comment: Don't get why there is inner `ForEach`... unless it is simplified sample you should be using single call to `Regex.Replace` instead of building multiple copies of whole file content.

Comment: Every instance of every OldGuid must be replaced with the corresponding NewGuid in the given file.

Comment: @bostIT does not explain why there is `Parallel.Foreach` so... Even if it would work correctly (which is not as described in Erik's answer), why would you want to create a lot of strings replacing one Guid at a time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, there is a race condition.**

```
fileText = fileText.Replace(guidObj.Value.OldGuid, guidObj.Value.NewGuid);
```

If two separate threads start this operation, they both will start on the original string. Whichever one completes first will write to the `fileText` variable. When the second one completes, it will also write to the same variable. But since both threads are operating on the original string, when the second one completes the changes made by the first one will be overwritten.

Comment: The outer one doesn't have an issue because the variables are local to the lambda. Each thread will have its own variables to work on.

Comment: It looks like all the filenames at unique, since he's iterating over the keys of a dictionary. The standard .Net dictionary restricts keys to be unique.